# How to send complex body in the request with rest assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

How can I send a body like this on request?

{
"censored1": "String1",
"censored2": "String2",
"censored3": "String3",
"censored4": "String4",
"censored5": "String5",
"censored6": {
"censored7" "YZF2CWsvAbBMd / Los7LZPaqut5eQ58mYWbFaXC7g4mLxoQOGly5KfZOLNaoUURzd9Tj5OuVy0SBrBlvRw4krtFwz5klIW4Z9uaJ6QYkDKeYLMrikvvNYXgirU7uWnL0TFOdhnpDxPnC7evIPHAfI1MaTHcErKAy2eyb8ycL81rmu / q4gioVLbO4PBBt4ufNp9BX0FociAFqpM3cpABh3uXLE2j2rFsSflKRICkMKTcgEr6hE15mbTD6q7vjGFfEr3Xpx7a2xbxLfxwmeHbel71HM0 + FydudVQQr0GztWDtaQdUOJSaQF21ZR4iS0WK / qaAa1eumybcfzuxl9SwI4Aw \ u003d \ u003d"
"Month", "Dyd3nCmyTXi177TqMCy7w3X8DMJplFiQmLoss3ZFPkBXKdZxCiwfiQ2ZtTbU640 / h2aoZXBJPD + uSgK / SxIVeFOHrYEfqhaQd2zJjyeqM88DeI2cB8eueNeR4ed0f0UH1ICpqDZARozqbbeIyaeiMZBPW2RsaNIqc2CZRJbGVnZs68Agav / Ow9Jb3rlPfr2s / zheaFdXTrUgcv1oP5FCx98dk0CV / hIJuLClilMkZnUCXFL2K4j6Il1DvJAj3bDqVBqUlLYjYlQx0FE9uXkyipyElGG0HOS9DgbNWaxhPA4eGQpUbXJOplNh3StADUgvZhIroA5TZopGMQfKsPnyWA \ u003d \ u003d"
"Year", "CExWSmbgbLpO5JpTRtiUq / hiJmDoz1hGnI5lnArYLknslsqMbnDwzck3e3jZpKWi70vQ1vCuKGnQwTElSbBUAXh0vQV / IGox1UlsjnbqxknBtnz47pXF5Khzhaum9EkEi9Im1foBmcvysc9Z / rrn / zYfGuVCszYgEwAOLZKU7MB8ucZP9NtyGGViqb8bpYqyawJOPBVGh7YEcsAzGzkR0WpaQPBdz2QiIo0eglTU2ArnWjsUHhH3UrTqxo8m71nK22akz6UrcN6mCS44ebIf3eghrx5Ux702zg4y321RwGPp2Hi0QVRKFGm9iSATOBOwTQff5X4lcE7bm5CeQpuSJA \ u003d \ u003d"
"censored8": "1",
"censored9": "404",
"Pin": "JdpQJXOXxxvQFXS1 / wEuFp + / xgrDS2 / WAc4sVJtRM1Lc260 + + // lzwPjBSe3by8lvvAmtse6gAyUtV1Z YGY91jj0jRbiQOxcFB6jfYxEjGQy / FyF9rYZDRTvuVz5y / AWaf8U4iZ + QbY3NswrK9Roa2qwp4w9SVi8NQO6SDg1DdbUWThpY2VoFt6OZzc9JyHyFBbNw / UamBiTpsc5ovDxqzgZPsEtKWvDObdcquoO8h3SC5A7Qra6HSL40yqSD + XEJ9iK3iGpKqOQP7c9zDvktmbVNodEFyxS + UkayaGOjnhZQSNiTrAUxidRKoBWsuAgJ0sKdRzbfxq8yd3s3EgHKg \ u003d \ u003d"
}
}

my method:

```
    Response response = given()
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .header("Content-type", "application/json;")
            .header("Session-Id", "1")
            .header("cellularNumber", billNumber)
            .when()
            //.body() ??
            .get(url)
            .then()
            .statusCode(statusCode).log().all()
            .extract()
            .response();

    String jsonResponse = response.getBody().print();

    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, ResponseLimitService.class);
}
```

Comment: You have already looked at sending JSON message, now you need to the body of your request, that is all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Response response = given()
    .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
    .header("Content-type", "application/json;")
    .header("Session-Id", "1")
    .header("cellularNumber", billNumber)
    .when()
    .body("{ \"your_json\": \"as_string\" }")
    .get(url)
    .then()
    .statusCode(statusCode).log().all()
    .extract()
    .response();
```